# Displaying multiple images in PrettyPhoto

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, prettyphoto

I am building a website, and on one of the pages is a section to show off some images. I thought that prettyPhoto looked good, and decided to use it.

Right now I have a square 'box' in bootstrap with 2 col-md-4 rows (6 total). Each image has a hover state that changes on hover, showing a icon to click on, and from there prettyPhoto opens.

I am not sure how to add multiple images to prettyPhoto given the documentation, but there are examples of it on their documentation, I just haven't had any luck implementing them.

Here is my code

**html**

```
 <div class="row centered">
          <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item web-design">
            <div class="he-wrap tpl6">
               <img src="images/portfolio-2/crate-of-california.jpg" height="450px" width="600px" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                  <div class="he-view">
                    <div class="bg a0" data-animate="fadeIn">
                        <h3 class="a1" data-animate="fadeInDown">Crate of California</h3>
                         <a data-rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" href="images/portfolio-2/crate-of-california.jpg" width="600" height="486" class="dmbutton a2" data-animate="fadeInUp"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                     </div><!-- he bg -->
                </div><!-- he view -->    
            </div><!-- he wrap -->
          </div>
```

**js**

```
(function($) {
// prettyPhoto
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('a[data-gal]').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).attr('rel', jQuery(this).data('gal'));
        });     
        jQuery("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animationSpeed:'slow',theme:'light_square',slideshow:false,overlay_gallery: false,social_tools:false,deeplinking:false,allow_resize:true});
    });     
})(jQuery);
```

I can post the css if needed, but most of it has nothing to do with the problem.

Does anyone know how I could display multiple images (galleries) per image with prettyPhoto? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get this figured out, the documentation on the site is not very good at all and it took me a couple hours to figure out, so hopefully someone gets some use out of this.

Basically, I was trying to display an image gallery for each of the 6 images in my 2x3 rows. The code ended up being;

**html**

```
  <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item web-design">
            <div class="he-wrap tpl6">
               <img src="images/portfolio-2/kenneth-cole.jpg" height="450px" width="600px" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                  <div class="he-view">
                    <div class="bg a0" data-animate="fadeIn">
                        <h3 class="a1" data-animate="fadeInDown">Kenneth Cole</h3>
                         <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery2]" href="images/portfolio-2/kenneth-cole.jpg" class="dmbutton a2" data-animate="fadeInUp"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                         <a href="images/portfolio-images/kennethcole2.png" class="lightbox-image lightbox-hide" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery2]" title="Another Title 2"></a>
                         <a href="images/portfolio-images/kennethcole3.png" class="lightbox-image lightbox-hide" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery2]" title="Another Title 2"></a>
                         <a href="images/portfolio-images/kennethcole4.png" class="lightbox-image lightbox-hide" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery2]" title="Another Title 2"></a>
                     </div><!-- he bg -->
                </div><!-- he view -->    
            </div><!-- he wrap -->
          </div>



      .....
        <!-- beneath your main content, before your closing body tag 
the social tools (twitter and facebook sharing) are in there by default, so this takes it off -->
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({social_tools:''});
            });
        </script>
        </body>
```

Basically you just have to make sure you're 'trigger' is `rel=prettyPhoto`, and you can have multiple ones of each div. prettyPhoto has helpers and buttons once you get multiple images showing up.